# WebRTC: video blinks when upgrading

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

## description

WebRTC sample https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/upgrade/ is about adding video track to an existing peer connection which contains an audio track. I revise it a little bit, and make a reverse. I change the program from adding video track to audio track to adding audio track to video track. Then I find that the `remoteVideo` tag blinks when this line is being executed.

`remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];`

In other words, it will blink when we add an audio track to a html5 video tag which is playing a video track.

## expectation

No blink.

## question

Is it possible to add audio track perfectly (no blink)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue with current in-browser implementations of WebRTC.

A known workaround is to create a new `HTMLVideoElement` that displays the new stream, and then substitute the old element with the new one in the DOM.  Don't forget to set the old element's `srcObject` to `null` so it can be garbage collected.